# Block filter is output to category page

Tags: magento2.2, template

A block filter is output only for a specific category page.
I do not know the cause.

[image]

Is there something wrong with the following templates?

app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_LayeredNavigation/templates/layer/ view.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php
/**
 * Category layered navigation
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation
 */
?>

<?php if ($block->canShowBlock()): ?>
    <div class="block filter">
        <div class="block-title filter-title">
            <strong><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Shop By') ?></strong>
        </div>

        <div class="block-content filter-content">
            <?= $block->getChildHtml('state') ?>

            <?php if ($block->getLayer()->getState()->getFilters()): ?>
                <div class="block-actions filter-actions">
                    <a href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getClearUrl() ?>" class="action clear filter-clear"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Clear All') ?></span></a>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php $wrapOptions = false; ?>
            <?php foreach ($block->getFilters() as $filter): ?>
                <?php if (!$wrapOptions): ?>
                    <strong role="heading" aria-level="2" class="block-subtitle filter-subtitle"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Shopping Options') ?></strong>
                    <dl class="filter-options" id="narrow-by-list">
                <?php $wrapOptions = true; endif; ?>
                    <?php if ($filter->getItemsCount()): ?>
                        <dt role="heading" aria-level="3" class="filter-options-title"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__($filter->getName())) ?></dt>
                        <dd class="filter-options-content"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getChildBlock('renderer')->render($filter) ?></dd>
                    <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php if ($wrapOptions): ?>
                </dl>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

My environment is Magento 2.2.6.

Answer (score 0):

Check category settings in admin if `Anchor` is set to yes or not.

When `Anchor` is set to “Yes,” includes the “filter by attribute” section in the layered navigation.

Reference Link : https://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/catalog/categories-display-settings.html

Comment: Of course, the setting has been confirmed. I added a screenshot to my question.

Comment: @mr.hironobu Sorry, but I am a bit confused, if you want to show the filters or not. According to your settings, the block filter should not appear.

Comment: That's why I am in trouble.
I would like to see the setting of attribute (is_anchor) from the database table for each category, but do you know the SQL query?